# importing class from one file to another file java package does not exist

Tags: java, java-package

I have two files:
file1:

```
package firstclass.dep;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        final firstclass abc = new firstclass() ;
        abc.dep();
}
}
```

File2:

```
class firstclass{
    public void dep(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
}
}
```

I am trying to import first-class file to main class file
and its showing me error:

> Main.java:1: error: package firstclass does not exist import
> firstclass.dep;
> ^ 1 error

Comment: package shouldn't be the class name!! it should be the name of the folder that contains Class.
you have to import firstclass: import firstClass;
ps: try to name your class with capital letters(FirstClass)

Comment: import only declare package name, not include class name and method name.

Comment: @IssaKhodadadi it didn't work

Comment: @ShiviSingla both your classes are in a same package?

Comment: @IssaKhodadadi by same package you mean, if you mean same file, then yes they are. 
This is the new code:
import FirstClass;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        final FirstClass abc = new FirstClass() ;
        abc.dep();
    }
}


File2:


class FirstClass{
    public void dep(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
}
}